# Markov chain on $k$-length words on the state space.

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains

Let $S$ be the state space (finite) of a Markov chain. We write $p(x, y)$ to denote the probability of transitioning from $x\in S$ to $y\in S$ in one step.
We then naturally get a Markov chain on $S^k$, where the probability of transitioning from $(x_0, x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1})$ to $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k)$ is $p(x_{k-1}, x_k)$.

Are there some general results known about such chains?
This seems like a very natural concept but I am not able to locate any source where this is discussed.

As an example, consider $S=\{a, b\}$ where $p(a, b)=p(b, a)=1$. Even though this chain is irreducible, it can be easily seen that the induced chain on $S^2$ is not irreducible.

Comment: The reverse of what you're considering is known – turning a higher-order Markov chain with memory into a memoryless chain by considering the chain on the tuples – see the section "Variations" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Discrete-time_Markov_chain).

Comment: It is indeed a very natural construction, and it is used routinely.  From the point of view of processes, the new Markov chain is essentially the same as the original one, since the two are related by the strongest type of isomorphism (finitary, with bounded memory).

Comment: @Blackbird Can you elaborate on your comment. In particular, can you spell out what is meant by isomorphsim here. The example I gave show that an irreducible Markov chain can give rise to a reducible one, so I can't see how the two chains can be isomorphic in a meaningful way.

Comment: You are right, as you defined it, the new chain can have extra transient states that are left forever in $k-1$ time steps.  There is a variant in which instead of $S^k$, you choose $\{a_1a_2\cdots a_k\in S^k: p(a_i,a_{i+1})>0\}$ as the state space of the new Markov chain.

Comment: The kind of isomorphism I mentioned is bijective sliding block maps (a.k.a. topological conjugacy) between the sets of trajectories of the two Markov chain.  See e.g., [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symbolic_dynamics)

Comment: @Blackbird Okay. Thanks. Let me try to work out the details and get back if I fail.